# Performance relating to Object Instances

Tags: performance, instances

Just a simple performance question.

When using object instances, the same vertex data is used for another object (like an exact duplicate) causing much less memory usage when building up the rendering (one dataset instead of two etc.).

But I wonder now: If I have a mesh with ~500 vertices, and I use this 50+ times in my scene, when is the point reached that I won't save any more memory because of the sheer **amount** of instances? I mean, every instance is yet **another** object, right?

So what will be better? **One** object with 50*500 vertices (25k vertices) OR **50** objects sharing the same 500 vertices data?

Comment: If the model has a texture, then the instance will be better.